# Extra index in list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a piece of code where I try to add elements in an array at specific index.

```
N_5min = np.zeros(100)
x = [10, 20, 30, 40]
print N_5min
x1 = [int(i) for i in x]

ls_5min = N_5min.tolist()
print len(ls_5min)
l = 1
for i in range(len(x1)):

    ls_5min.append(ls_5min.insert((x1[i]+ l), 10)) # Adds element at the x[i]th position incremented by 'l'
    l = l+1
print (ls_5min)
```

Here I am inserting the number 10 to the array of zeros at index 11, 22, 33, and 44. so Now the length of the list ls_5min should be 104. But I get its length as 108, with the last 4 elements being 'None'. why is the length 108 and not 104?

Comment: Look at what `insert` returns? Perform the `append(insert...) once and study the result. In other words test the pieces to make sure they doing what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace

```
ls_5min.append(ls_5min.insert((x1[i]+ l), 10))
```

By

```
ls_5min.insert(x1[i]+ l, 10)
```

The insert command adds an item to the list, and returns None. Then, the append command adds the returned None at the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you.. I did not know that :)

Answer (score 1):

Because in each iteration, you append the return value (**default is None**) of insert function to ls_5min. So you insert a value and append a none to ls_5min in each iteration. So the length is 108 rather than 104.

you need change

```
ls_5min.append(ls_5min.insert((x1[i]+ l), 10))
```

to

```
ls_5min.insert((x1[i]+ l), 10)
```